Flutter wWeb: blank screen on launch
I'm facing an issue while trying to run a new Flutter project on a web browser (Chrome or Edge). When I run the app, I only see a blank white screen with that flutter's blue loading bar at the top, and it doesn't progress beyond that.and i have a random error in console example :
I'm facing an issue while trying to run a new Flutter project on a web browser (Chrome or Edge). When I run the app, I only see a blank white screen with that flutter's blue loading bar at the top, and it doesn't progress beyond that.and i have a random error in console example :
 `localhost/:1 \<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"\> is deprecated. Please include \<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"\>
 require.js:143 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: () =\> CanvasKitInit
 http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
 at makeError (require.js:168:17)
 at intakeDefines (require.js:1254:36)
 at Object.localRequire \[as require\] (require.js:1446:21)
 at requirejs (require.js:1797:24)
 at req.config (require.js:1805:16)
 at main_module.bootstrap.js:3:9`

I found that deleting the web folder or index.html resolves the issue
is there another way to resolve this issue without deleting the web folder?
I have tried the following steps without success:
Running flutter clean
Clearing the cache
Using flutter run -d chrome
I found that deleting the web folder or index.html resolves the issue
is there another way to resolve this issue without deleting the web folder?
I have tried the following steps without success:
Running flutter clean
Clearing the cache
Using flutter run -d chrome
